# Reading Embedded Object in Excel File

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have an excel file contains `Attachment column`, which has another excel object embedded into it.

I need to read that embedded excel file and process its data.

So far i used [Excel Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) to read the normal excel file and retrieve as DataSet.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

//Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

// Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();


while (excelReader.Read())
{
    //excelReader.GetInt32(0);
}

excelReader.Close();
```

[image]

`Now i want to read the embedded object(excel file)`

**Is there any dll/component/code which will help us to read embedded object inside excel file?**

***Note:*** I dont have a Microsoft Office Package installed in server. So i dont want to use Microsoft.Interoperability package

Comment: Do you have a sample file like this posted somewhere?

Comment: @SimonMourier I added that for you. Please see the file from here https://github.com/MuraliM/TestRepo/blob/master/Sample_Excel_File.xlsx?raw=true

Comment: This 'Excel Reader' tool just doesn't support this type of data. I have tried EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and it doesn't work either. You'd have to modify the source of Excel Reader to handle this. Technically, the files are present in the XLSX, if you rename it as a .ZIP file and open it, you will see they are located in the `xl\embeddings` path.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Thanks a lot. Do we have any other simple way to read this xl\embeddings using some FileStream and then take the contained file and read use of ExcelReader

Comment: The best you can do right now is open the file using any .ZIP library that suits you, and extract the file as entries in the .ZIP.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Sure I give a try. How do we know the exact path of x\embeddings to extract?

Comment: It's located in the some of the XML files of the package, you need to fully understand Open Package Specifications/Office Open XML (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) on which the XLSX format is based for this, so it's not that easy...